# ¿Cómo puedo colocar botones en cualquier lado libremente en Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Tengo un grave problema en Android Studio y es que todos los botones que coloco en Android studio siempre se quedan en la esquina superior izquierda.

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir el código de tu `layout`? No podemos saber que es lo que falla si no nos das mas información. Pasate por el [tour],[ask] y [mcve].

Comment: Dependiendo del tipo de Layout que estés usando, tienen diferente forma de acomodar los botones y otros elementos. Y además cada uno tiene sus propias propiedades para decirle como desplegar los botones y otros Views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando creas un Layout o una nueva activity por lo general tiene este codigo

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

   </LinearLayout>
```

Prueba cambiando el LinearLayout por RelativeLayout de esta manera

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

   </RelativeLayout >
```

Comment: Hey gracias, me sirvió con RelativeLayout